# ASSIMP mesh loader leak

Tags: assimp

Facing a leak in ASSIMP mesh loader

as per valgrind, I lose 80 bytes:

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>      // C++ importer interface
#include <assimp/cimport.h>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

int main()
{
    aiReleaseImport(aiImportFile("../Geometry/ModeLoader/Model1Spider_3.fbx",aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Quality));
    return 0;
}
```

I have installed this library using apt-get (using Linux Mint 21)

details are also mentioned here https://sourceforge.net/p/assimp/discussion/817654/thread/7d5f8d4f1b/?limit=25#cad1

Answer (score 1):

There was some problem with the model , spider.fbx from sample works fine.